# Typo3 Fluid templates compiled to PHP code?

Tags: typo3

can someone tell me if Typo3 Fluid templates (*.html) would be precompiled as PHP code and stored in the cache, as Symfony-Twig templates are? If yes, where are the cached PHP-files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Fluid templates are compiled into php files and put into a cache. In TYPO3, you typically find these cache files in typo3temp/var/cache/code/fluid_template